# Store the shifted value

Tags: assembly, x86

For example, i have:

```
mov eax, 4012e0         ; eax = 4012e0h
shr eax, 8              ; eax = 4012h
```

Notice that, the **"e0"** has been shifted. But i want to store the **"e0"** for further use. Can anyone suggest me a solution how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Does simply retrieving before shifting like `mov cl, al` work?

Comment: @MikeCAT: Or better, `movzx ecx, al` to zero-extend the low byte into a full register.  You rarely want to write a partial register and merge a new byte with the existing upper bytes.  But yeah, anything you want later should be saved to another register, or to memory if you're out of registers.  (`push eax`, or `mov [esp + 4], al` or whatever.)

Comment: If the shift count happens to be something other than 8 then you can do something like `mov ecx, eax` \ `and ecx, (1 << x) - 1` where you insert the shift count as the constant `x`.